# How to limit disks IO of Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, io, cgroups

I am working with Docker containers and observed that they tend to generate too much disk IOs.

I found the `--device-write-bps` option which seem to address my need of limiting the disk IOs.

However, this option expects a path to a device, but the latest Docker drivers do not allow me to determine what to set (device is `overlay` with `overlay2` storage driver). Here is what `df -h` outputs in my case:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          59G  5.3G   51G  10% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           994M     0  994M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1        59G  5.3G   51G  10% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           994M     0  994M   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           994M     0  994M   0% /sys/firmware
```

Is the option compatible with the latest drivers? If yes, would someone know what is the path to set?

Thanks!

Comment: The mount command may give you some more help

Comment: Tried it as well with no more useful information, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was mistaken by the doc. The device to specify for the `--device-write-bps` option is the device of the host machine. So the `mount` command is useful, but needs to be run on the host ^^